# UIBarButtonItem does not get displayed

Tags: ios

I am trying to add UIBarButtonItem to navigationItem but it does not gets displayed

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    lbl =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100, 200, 40)];

    lbl.text=@"Hello,World";

    lbl.textAlignment= NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    [self.view addSubview:lbl];


    UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]

                                    initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"house.png"]

                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain

                                    target:self

                                    action:@selector(goHome:)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;

    }
```

app delegate code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{
    ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc] init];

    [controller.navigationItem setTitle:@"Main View"];

    UINavigationController *navcontroller =[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];

    self.window.rootViewController=navcontroller;

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;



}
```

Comment: is there a "`house.png`" file in your built app?

Comment: Or make sure it is `house.png` in built not `House.png`. Case sensitivity matters.